# How to change the font settings of SuperPutty permanently?

Tags: ssh, fonts, putty

I am using superputty to connect remotely with several machines.
The problem is that the fonts are huge.

I temporally solve this by changing the font *every time I connect*, rightclicking the tab and going to [Change Settings] and [Windows]->[Appereance] and changing the font.

However this is not permanent. Once I connect another machine, the default huge font is there.
I tried to change it in "saved sessions" but it did not work

How can I change the default font permanently to make it more appealing.

EDIT
By applying the suggestion now an error message appears

[image: error]

Comment: Save it to *"Default Settings"*.

Comment: OMG. I did that and now when I connect a message appears "Process Window not found" and I cannot connect anymore to anything .....For some convenience I lost the use of the tool

Comment: I think the problem this suggestion created is related to http://forum.gns3.net/topic7617.html

Comment: Where exactly does the message appear? Please post a screenshot. The link in your comment does not work for me.

Comment: What a mess... it is unrecoverable....I have uninstalled, delete the window registry item, installed again.. all because some fonts....(sigh)